# Magento 2 How to remove inline Translate

Tags: magento2, translate

I translated few words before with `Translate inline` but now I would like to remove those inline translations.

Is it possible to remove it?

Comment: Would you like to remove those translations or the magento translate inline tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline translations are stored in the database. The table is `translation`. Just look up the entries you want to remove and do so. Don't forget to flush your cache afterwards to see the changes.